# Can I implement my own OverflowStrategy?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

Is it possible (or will it be possible in the future) to implement my own [OverflowStrategy](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/index.html#akka.stream.OverflowStrategy$) as a function of the current buffer of the element? Or there's a particular reason to not allow that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `sealed` in `sealed abstract class OverflowStrategy` in [akka.stream.OverflowStrategy](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/index.html#akka.stream.OverflowStrategy), no way you could do that.